# Explicit equation for the dual hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$. Assume $X$ is defined by some homogenous polynomial $F$. Then, is there a way to write the equation for $X^\vee$ explicitly?

(This is related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065598/singular-locus-of-dual-hypersurfaces))

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve#Equations and try to mimic the technique there.

Comment: @DKS Thanks! But other from the conic, for hypersurfaces in higher degree, it is not easy to eliminate the parameters. For example, for $X$ defined by $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$, in the way you suggest, we can get the equation for the dual curve $X^{3/2}+Y^{3/2}+Z^{3/2}=0$ . On the other hand, it should be a curve of degree $6$, so I expect an explicit polynomial of degree $6$, which is not clear to me. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Use $(X^{3/2}+Y^{3/2}+Z^{3/2})(X^{3/2}-Y^{3/2}+Z^{3/2})(X^{3/2}+Y^{3/2}-Z^{3/2})(X^{3/2}-Y^{3/2}-Z^{3/2})=0$ ?

Comment: @random Yes, I think it is in the special case. But in general, it is not easy to get the polynomial from the parametric equations.